# Select text without blocking keyboard input in ConEmu?

Tags: terminal, conemu, selection

In ConEmu, if I select some text, I cannot type anything in the terminal anymore. I need to press Enter first so as to clear the selection. This is different from other terminals in Linux for instance (which means out of habit, I'm pressing Enter in Linux even though it's not needed).

Is there any option to prevent this, basically allow me to use the keyboard when a selection is active (or maybe clear the selection as soon as start typing)?

Comment: Simple: "Reset selection on input".

Comment: Brilliant, I had a look at this setting page and completely missed this parameter. Thanks a lot!